# Counting commutative binary operations on a set S with n elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I understand why on a set S with n elements there are $n^{n^2}$ binary operations, but how exactly do you count the number of commutative binary operations? I saw this post: [Counting binary operations on a set with $n$ elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375529/counting-binary-operations-on-a-set-with-n-elements) but I do not really understand their answer. For a set with 4 elements I get that there are $4^{12}$ commutative operations, not $4^{10}$.

Comment: What do you not understand, and how did you get $4^{12}$?

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough, my first time posting. After reading the other comment, I realised that I has a misunderstanding of what a binary option really was. I got $4^{12}$ as I counted every square in the 4x4 besides the diagonal. Im not quite Sure why I did that to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt to re-explain the answer you linked.

Consider the simple example $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$. To define a binary operation $m : S \times S \to S$, we must define $m(a,b)$ for all $a,b \in S$. Pictorally, we have to fill in the following grid with elements of $S$:

[image: grid1]

However, if we want $m$ to be commutative, we need $m(a,b) = m(b,a)$ for all $a,b \in S$. So, it suffices to define $m(a,b)$ for $a \geq b$, i.e. we only need to fill in the shaded part of the grid:

[image: grid2]

Once we've defined the values of $m$ on the shaded part of the grid, we use the desired commutativity to determine the values elsewhere. And, importantly, *any* assignment of values on the shaded portion of the grid will produce a commutative binary operation.

So, the number of commutative binary operations is equal to the number of possible functions from the shaded squares to $S$, which is $4$ to the power of the number of shaded squares. Now all we have to do is count how many shaded squares there are!

Well, the grid overall has $4^2$ squares. $4$ of these are on the diagonal, $\frac{4^2-4}{2}$ are above the diagonal, and $\frac{4^2-4}{2}$ are below the diagonal. The shaded region is the part on or below the diagonal, which contains a total of $4 + \frac{4^2-4}{2} = \frac{4^2+4}{2} = 10$ squares.

We conclude that there are $4^{10}$ commutative binary operations on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Awesome explanation, extremely helpful. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

A binary operation is a mapping from $S \times S$ to $S$.To each ordered pair from $S \times S$, there are $|S|$ possibilities of a paring from the codomain.  That means if $|S|=n$, then n gets multiplied as many times as there are ordered pairs, so the total is $n^{n^2}$.

There are fewer ordered pairs to work with for a commutative operation since $*(x,y)=*(y,x)$.

So the question becomes how many ordered pairs are we working, and what may they be mapped to?

Suppose $x,y \in S$. We have  one set of ordered pairs where $x=y$ and another set where $x\ne y$. There are $n$  ordered pairs of the form $*(x,x)$ and there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ordered pairs where $x\ne y$.

That's a total number of ordered pairs of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{2n}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. And as in the previous case, we multiply $n$ by itself as many times as there are ordered pairs so $n^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use little Gauß here:  $$1+2+\dots +n=n(n+1)/2.$$

Since the number of squares on or below the diagonal is just $1+2+\dots +n.$

We get, in general,  $$n^{\frac {n(n+1)}2}$$ commutative binary operations on a set of $n$ elements. Because the Cayley table is symmetric.